# GeoSPARQL query with FILTER geof:sfContains or geof:sfIntersects or geof:sfOverlaps returns no results when run from Java:JenaParliament

Tags: geospatial, sparql, jena, geo

I am using Jena, JenaParliament, Parliamnet to use GeoSPARQL queries to the Parliment RDF store. Simple SPARQL queries work fine, but when i use some GeoSPARQL query e.g.

```
SELECT * WHERE {?bGeom geo:asWKT ?bWKT . FILTER (geof:sfIntersects(?bWKT, "Polygon((1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 1 0))"^^sf:wktLiteral))}

SELECT * WHERE {?bGeom geo:asWKT ?bWKT . FILTER (geof:sfOverlaps(?bWKT, "Polygon((1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 1 0))"^^sf:wktLiteral))}

SELECT * WHERE {?bGeom geo:asWKT ?bWKT . FILTER (geof:sfTouches(?bWKT, "Polygon((1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 1 0))"^^sf:wktLiteral))}

SELECT * WHERE {?bGeom geo:asWKT ?bWKT . FILTER (geof:sfCrosses(?bWKT, "Polygon((0 0, 1 0, 0 1, 0 0))"^^sf:wktLiteral))}
```

The output is a null `ResultSet` (Blank Table) with a Runtime WARNING :

```
WARN [main] (E_Function.java:70) - URI <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/sfIntersects> has no registered function factory.
```

The same warning and results are obtained for other `geof:sfFunction` 's. I have tried the same queries on the PARLIMENT QUICK START distribution using SPARQL Endpoit at `http://localhost:8080/parliament/sparql` , and valid outputs are returned when run on Jetty server.

The code used to fire the GeoSPARQL query from java is same as illustrated in Parliament User Guide.pdf is given below:

```
void useParliamentModel(){
      Model kbModel = createParliamentModel();
      FileManager.get().readModel( kbModel, "Path to source owl/rdf file");
      String sparqlQueryString = "PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>" +
                                    "PREFIX geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>" +
                                    "PREFIX sf: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#>"+
                                    "PREFIX afn: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/function#>"+
                                    "PREFIX fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>"+
                                    "PREFIX gml: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/gml#>"+
                                    "PREFIX j.0:<http://www.opengis.net/def/geosparql/#>"+
                                    "PREFIX my:<http://example.org/ApplicationSchema#>"+
                                    //"SELECT * WHERE {?s ?o my:PlaceOfInterest}"; ------->>>>  THIS QUERY RUNS FINE
                                    "SELECT * WHERE {?bGeom geo:asWKT ?bWKT . FILTER (geof:sfIntersects(?bWKT, \"Polygon((1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 1 0))\"^^sf:wktLiteral))}";  //give Waring No result
                                    //"SELECT * WHERE {?bGeom geo:asWKT ?bWKT . FILTER (geof:sfOverlaps(?bWKT, \"Polygon((1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 1 0))\"^^sf:wktLiteral))}";   //give Waring No result
                                    //"SELECT * WHERE {<http://example.org/ApplicationSchema#F> ?s ?o }";  //-------->>> This Query runs Fine
                                    //"SELECT ?f WHERE { my:A my:hasExactGeometry ?aGeom . ?aGeom geo:asWKT ?aWKT . ?f my:hasExactGeometry ?fGeom . ?fGeom geo:asWKT ?fWKT . FILTER (geof:sfContains(?aWKT, ?fWKT) && !sameTerm(?aGeom, ?fGeom))}";  /// return a blank table
      String r;
      try{
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(sparqlQueryString, kbModel);
       ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect(); 
       r = printResultsWithResultSetFormatter(results, SparqlQuery.OutputType.TEXT);
      }
      finally
      {
        if (kbModel != null && !kbModel.isClosed())
        {
          kbModel.close();
          kbModel = null;
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Query Results are: \n----------\n"+ r);
    }
```

Furthermore: to my observation we need to create indexses for the dataset inserted when using Parliament QuickStart Distribution from the indexes.jsp page. Do we need to create/initialize indexes from the java code before firing any geoSparql query?? if yes then how?

Please Help!! it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make spatial queries work, the following code should be used for Initializing the model, using `JenaParliament` and `Parliament` JAVA API:

```
 public static void initializeJPStore(){

            KbGraph graph;
            KbGraphStore graphStore;
            SpatialIndexFactory spatialIndexFactory;
            SpatialIndex spatialIndex;
        boolean createIndex = true;

        spatialIndexFactory = new SpatialIndexFactory();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(Constants.GEOMETRY_INDEX_TYPE, Constants.GEOMETRY_INDEX_RTREE);
        properties.setProperty(Constants.GEOSPARQL_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        spatialIndexFactory.configure(properties);
        IndexFactoryRegistry.getInstance().register(spatialIndexFactory);
        graph = KbGraphFactory.createDefaultGraph(); //Dir path taken from ParliamentConfig.txt
        graphStore = new KbGraphStore(graph);
        graphStore.initialize();

        if (createIndex) {

            spatialIndex = spatialIndexFactory.createIndex(graph, null);
            IndexManager.getInstance().register(graph, null, spatialIndexFactory, spatialIndex);
            graphStore.setIndexingEnabled(KbGraphStore.DEFAULT_GRAPH_NODE, true);

         }

        Model model = ModelFactory.createModelForGraph(graph);
        OntModel ontModel= ModelToOntModel(model);
        FileManager.get().readModel(ontModel, "Path/to/Source RDF/OWL file");
        //System.out.println(IndexManager.getInstance().getIndexes(graph).get(0).size()); to keep a check of IndexSize
    }
```

From my observations and experiments: you must create the `Indexes`, register them with `IndexFactory`, and then register both the `Index` and the `IndexFactory` with the `IndexManager`, or the GeoSPARQL queries won't work. The ARQ engine makes requests to the `IndexManager` for indexes of a given model/graph for execution of the GeoSPARQL queries/functions. After initializing the Triple Store as above, one can fire a SPARQL/GeoSPARQL query indifferently without making changes to the code for invoking a SPARQL query.

Note: As for the problem stated above about `sf:function` being not registered, I guess that gets solved when we configure the `Properties.setProperty(Constants.GEOSPARQL_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE.toString());`.  But I am not sure of this.

And please don't forget to `close()` the Model, graphs, and index as well.